# Tensorflow restore `tf.Session` saved checkpoint using `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession`

Tags: session, tensorflow, checkpoint

I have code for training a CNN using `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession`.

When I create a new `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession` I can pass the `checkpoint` directory as an input parameter to the session and it will automatically restore the latest saved `checkpoint` it could find. And I can set up the `hooks` to train until some step. For example, if the `checkpoint`'s step is `150,000` and I would like to train until `200,000` I will put the `last_step` to `200,000`.

The above process works perfectly as long as the latest `checkpoint` was saved using a `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession`. However, if I try to restore a `checkpoint` that was saved using a normal `tf.Session` then all hell breaks loose. It can't find some keys in the graph and all.

The training is done with this:

```
with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(
    checkpoint_dir=FLAGS.retrain_dir,
    hooks=[tf.train.StopAtStepHook(last_step=FLAGS.max_training_steps),
           tf.train.NanTensorHook(loss),
           _LoggerHook()],
    config=tf.ConfigProto(
        log_device_placement=FLAGS.log_device_placement)) as mon_sess:
  while not mon_sess.should_stop():
    mon_sess.run(train_op)
```

If the `checkpoint_dir` attribute had a folder with no checkpoints, this will start all over. If it had a `checkpoint` that was saved from a previous training session, it will restore the latest `checkpoint` and will continue training.

Now, I am restoring the latest `checkpoint` and modifying some variables and saving them:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)

ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.train_dir)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
    # Restores from checkpoint
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    print(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    restored_step = ckpt.model_checkpoint_path.split('/')[-1].split('-')[-1]
    FLAGS.max_training_steps = int(restored_step) + FLAGS.max_training_steps
  else:
    print('No checkpoint file found')
    return

  prune_convs(sess)
  saver.save(sess, FLAGS.retrain_dir+"model.ckpt-"+restored_step)
```

As you can see, just before `saver.save...` I am pruning all convolutional layers in the network. No need to describe how and why is that done. The point is that the network is in fact modified. Then I save the network to a `checkpoint`.

Now, if I deploy test on the saved modified network, the test works just fine. However, when I try to run the `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession` on the `checkpoint` that was saved, it says:

> Key conv1/weight_loss/avg not found in checkpoint

Also, I have noticed that the `checkpoint` that was saved with `tf.Session` has half of the size of the `checkpoint` that was saved with `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession`

I know I'm doing it wrong, any suggestions how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently, `tf.Saver` does not restore all variables from a `checkpoint`. I tried restoring and saving immediately and the output was half the size.

I used `tf.train.list_variables` to get all variables from latest `checkpoint` and then converted them into `tf.Variable` and created a `dict` from them. Then I passed the `dict` to `tf.Saver` and it restored all of my variables.

The next thing was to `initialize` all of the variables and then modify the weights.

Now it is working.